# Conditional compiling not work with F#/Visual Studio Mac with shared assembly (how workaround)

Tags: f#, conditional-compilation, visual-studio-mac

I have a shared assembly that encapsulate logic for all my projects, some on mobile and some for asp.net core and command line utilities.

Now, I need to customize how certains things work, like:

```
#if __MOBILE__
let ROOT_PATH = bundlePath()
#else
let ROOT_PATH = pathCombine __SOURCE_DIRECTORY__ ".."
#endif
```

However, if run the project the **MOBILE** is never hit from the iOS project. Now, I wish to not use injection, also because is several of this ifdefs around. Exist a way around this?

Comment: I've never used this feature myself but I've read that for [conditional compilation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/compiler-directives#conditional-compilation-directives) to work, you have to pass a define argument to the compiler `--define:__MOBILE__`. You probably should look at how to pass this argument to the compiler with Visual Studio Mac.